# Adding custom color doesn't render the default colours

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I've added a custom color in `tailwind.config.ts` called `twitterBlue` which successfully renders.

However all default colors have stopped rendering (i.e. background should be black & hover state should make the button red).

Am I overlooking/ignoring something?

---

This is code for a simple component and its image:

```js
export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center relative bg-black ">

      <button className='bg-twitterBlue w-[120px] rounded-3xl p-3 text-xl text-center hover:bg-red-400 transition duration-200'>
        Tweet
      </button>

    </div>
  )
}
```

---

Screenshot of the render

- Background (behind the button) should be black; Note that hover state also does not activate (i.e. turn red)

[image: background should be Black]

---

`tailwind.config.ts`

```html
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
    colors: {
      twitterBlue: "rgb(29, 155, 240)"
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

Versions:

- "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
- "next": "13.4.13",
- "postcss": "8.4.27",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing color configuration in [`theme.colors` removes the default color configuration entirely](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-custom-colors):

> If you’d like to completely replace the default color palette with your own custom colors, add your colors directly under the `theme.colors` section of your configuration file:

To retain the default colors and add your own in addition, [add the configuration to `theme.extend.colors`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#adding-additional-colors):

> If you’d like to add a brand new color to the default palette, add it in the `theme.extend.colors` section of your configuration file:

Thus, your configuration should look like:

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
      colors: {
        twitterBlue: "rgb(29, 155, 240)"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```